# Android emulator won't start, gets stuck in a loop

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I know there are a lot of issues with the Android emulator and that StackOverflow nearly overflows with questions about it. I know, I've been through most of them looking for an answer to my problem :)

I had the usual HAXM problems when I started but I fixed the VT settings in my BIOS and I reinstalled HAXM.

Now when I start my emulator, either through Android Studio or command line, it won't start and it gets stuck in a loop. The loop looks like this:

**Run output**

> Note: The environment variable $ANDROID_SDK_HOME is set, and the
>   emulator uses that variable to locate AVDs.
>
> This may result in the emulator failing to start if it cannot find the
>   AVDs in the folder pointed to by the
>
> given environment variable.
>
> ANDROID_SDK_HOME=C:\Users\maffe
>
> emulator: device fd:1160
>
> HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
>
> emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
>
> creating window 102 107 646 1147
>
> emulator: UpdateCheck: current version '24.4.1', last version '24.4.1'

**Logcat output**

> 01-22 05:48:36.770 6543-6543/? I/Netd: Netd 1.0 starting
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.771 6543-6543/? E/Netd: Failed to open
>   /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/optimistic_dad: No such file or
>   directory
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.771 6543-6543/? E/Netd: Failed to open
>   /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/optimistic_dad: No such file or directory
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.771 6543-6543/? E/Netd: Failed to open
>   /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/lo/optimistic_dad: No such file or directory
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.771 6543-6543/? E/Netd: Failed to open
>   /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/sit0/optimistic_dad: No such file or directory
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.771 6543-6543/? E/Netd: Failed to open
>   /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/use_optimistic: No such file or
>   directory
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.771 6543-6543/? E/Netd: Failed to open
>   /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/use_optimistic: No such file or directory
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.771 6543-6543/? E/Netd: Failed to open
>   /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/lo/use_optimistic: No such file or directory
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.772 6543-6543/? E/Netd: Failed to open
>   /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/sit0/use_optimistic: No such file or directory
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.875 6544-6544/? I/mediaserver: ServiceManager:
>   0xb5835620
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.875 6544-6544/? I/AudioFlinger: Using default 3000 mSec
>   as standby time.
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.876 6544-6544/? I/ServiceManager: Waiting for service
>   batterystats...
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.903 6545-6545/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit uid 0 <<<<<<
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.904 6545-6545/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.904 6545-6545/? I/art: option[0]=-Xzygote
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.904 6545-6545/? I/art: option[1]=-Xcheck:jni
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.904 6545-6545/? I/art: option[2]=-Xjnigreflimit:2000
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.904 6545-6545/? I/art:
>   option[3]=-Xstacktracefile:/data/anr/traces.txt
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.904 6545-6545/? I/art: option[4]=exit
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.904 6545-6545/? I/art: option[5]=vfprintf
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.904 6545-6545/? I/art: option[6]=sensitiveThread
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.904 6545-6545/? I/art: option[7]=-verbose:gc
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.904 6545-6545/? I/art: option[8]=-Xms4m
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.904 6545-6545/? I/art: option[9]=-Xmx2048m
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.904 6545-6545/? I/art:
>   option[10]=-XX:mainThreadStackSize=24K
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.905 6545-6545/? I/art:
>   option[11]=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_android_adb,suspend=n,server=y
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.905 6545-6545/? I/art:
>   option[12]=-Xlockprofthreshold:500
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.905 6545-6545/? I/art:
>   option[13]=-Ximage-compiler-option
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.905 6545-6545/? I/art: option[14]=--runtime-arg
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.905 6545-6545/? I/art:
>   option[15]=-Ximage-compiler-option
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.905 6545-6545/? I/art: option[16]=-Xms64m
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.905 6545-6545/? I/art:
>   option[17]=-Ximage-compiler-option
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.905 6545-6545/? I/art: option[18]=--runtime-arg
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.905 6545-6545/? I/art:
>   option[19]=-Ximage-compiler-option
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.905 6545-6545/? I/art: option[20]=-Xmx64m
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.905 6545-6545/? I/art:
>   option[21]=-Ximage-compiler-option
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.905 6545-6545/? I/art:
>   option[22]=--image-classes=/system/etc/preloaded-classes
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.905 6545-6545/? I/art: option[23]=-Xcompiler-option
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.905 6545-6545/? I/art: option[24]=--runtime-arg
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.905 6545-6545/? I/art: option[25]=-Xcompiler-option
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.905 6545-6545/? I/art: option[26]=-Xms64m
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.905 6545-6545/? I/art: option[27]=-Xcompiler-option
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.905 6545-6545/? I/art: option[28]=--runtime-arg
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.905 6545-6545/? I/art: option[29]=-Xcompiler-option
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.905 6545-6545/? I/art: option[30]=-Xmx512m
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.905 6545-6545/? I/art: option[31]=-Duser.language=en
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.905 6545-6545/? I/art: option[32]=-Duser.region=US
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.917 6545-6545/? W/art: Incomplete boot detected.
>   Pruning dalvik cache
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.924 6545-6545/? I/art: Pruning dalvik-cache since we
>   are relocating an image and will need to recompile
>
> 01-22 05:48:36.924 6545-6545/? I/art: RelocateImage:
>   /system/bin/patchoat --input-image-location=/system/framework/boot.art
>   --output-image-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@boot.art --input-oat-location=/system/framework/boot.oat --output-oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@boot.oat --instruction-set=x86 --base-offset-delta=-2789376
>
> 01-22 05:48:37.886 6544-6544/? I/ServiceManager: Waiting for service
>   batterystats...
>
> 01-22 05:48:38.558 6543-6543/? V/NatController:
>   runCmd(/system/bin/iptables -F natctrl_FORWARD) res=0
>
> 01-22 05:48:38.576 6543-6543/? V/NatController:
>   runCmd(/system/bin/iptables -A natctrl_FORWARD -j DROP) res=0
>
> 01-22 05:48:38.578 6543-6543/? V/NatController:
>   runCmd(/system/bin/iptables -t nat -F natctrl_nat_POSTROUTING) res=0
>
> 01-22 05:48:38.606 6543-6543/? V/NatController:
>   runCmd(/system/bin/iptables -F natctrl_tether_counters) res=0
>
> 01-22 05:48:38.608 6543-6543/? V/NatController:
>   runCmd(/system/bin/iptables -X natctrl_tether_counters) res=0
>
> 01-22 05:48:38.636 6543-6543/? V/NatController:
>   runCmd(/system/bin/iptables -N natctrl_tether_counters) res=0
>
> 01-22 05:48:38.633 6698-6698/? W/iptables: type=1400 audit(0.0:151):
>   avc: denied { module_request } for kmod="ipt_TCPMSS"
>   scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=system permissive=0
>
> 01-22 05:48:38.639 6543-6543/? V/NatController:
>   runCmd(/system/bin/iptables -t mangle -A natctrl_mangle_FORWARD -p tcp
>   --tcp-flags SYN SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu) res=1
>
> 01-22 05:48:38.896 6544-6544/? I/ServiceManager: Waiting for service
>   batterystats...
>
> 01-22 05:48:39.183 6745-6745/? W/iptables: type=1400 audit(0.0:152):
>   avc: denied { module_request } for kmod="ipt_owner"
>   scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=system permissive=0
>
> 01-22 05:48:39.183 6745-6745/? W/iptables: type=1400 audit(0.0:153):
>   avc: denied { module_request } for kmod="ipt_owner"
>   scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=system permissive=0
>
> 01-22 05:48:39.183 6745-6745/? W/iptables: type=1400 audit(0.0:154):
>   avc: denied { module_request } for kmod="ipt_owner"
>   scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=system permissive=0
>
> 01-22 05:48:39.188 6543-6543/? I/iptables: iptables: No
>   chain/target/match by that name.
>
> 01-22 05:48:39.196 6543-6543/? I/iptables: iptables terminated by
>   exit(1)
>
> 01-22 05:48:39.197 6543-6543/? E/BandwidthController:
>   runIptablesCmd(): res=1 status=256 failed /system/bin/iptables -A
>   bw_INPUT -m owner --socket-exists
>
> 01-22 05:48:39.193 6746-6746/? W/ip6tables: type=1400 audit(0.0:155):
>   avc: denied { module_request } for kmod="ip6t_owner"
>   scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=system permissive=0
>
> 01-22 05:48:39.193 6746-6746/? W/ip6tables: type=1400 audit(0.0:156):
>   avc: denied { module_request } for kmod="ip6t_owner"
>   scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=system permissive=0
>
> 01-22 05:48:39.193 6746-6746/? W/ip6tables: type=1400 audit(0.0:157):
>   avc: denied { module_request } for kmod="ip6t_owner"
>   scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=system permissive=0
>
> 01-22 05:48:39.202 6543-6543/? I/ip6tables: ip6tables: No
>   chain/target/match by that name.
>
> 01-22 05:48:39.202 6543-6543/? I/ip6tables: ip6tables terminated by
>   exit(1)
>
> 01-22 05:48:39.203 6543-6543/? E/BandwidthController:
>   runIptablesCmd(): res=1 status=256 failed /system/bin/ip6tables -A
>   bw_INPUT -m owner --socket-exists
>
> 01-22 05:48:39.216 6747-6747/? E/logwrapper: executing /system/bin/ip
>   failed: No such file or directory
>
> 01-22 05:48:39.228 6543-6543/? E/Netd: failed to flush rules
>
> 01-22 05:48:39.228 6543-6543/? E/CommandListener: failed to initialize
>   RouteController (Remote I/O error)
>
> 01-22 05:48:39.229 6543-6543/? D/MDnsDS: MDnsSdListener::Hander
>   starting up
>
> 01-22 05:48:39.229 6543-6752/? D/MDnsDS: MDnsSdListener starting to
>   monitor
>
> 01-22 05:48:39.230 6543-6752/? D/MDnsDS: Going to poll with pollCount
>   1
>
> 01-22 05:48:39.907 6544-6544/? I/ServiceManager: Waiting for service
>   batterystats...
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.357 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/gc/heap.cc:293]
>   Check failed: main_mem_map_1.get() != nullptr Failed anonymous
>   mmap(0x0, -2147483648, 0x3, 0x2, 4, 0): Out of memory
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.357 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/gc/heap.cc:293]
>   6fd57000-706cd000 rw-p 00000000 1f:01 7051
>   /data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@boot.art
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.357 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/gc/heap.cc:293]
>   706cd000-7215f000 r--p 00000000 1f:01 7052
>   /data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@boot.oat
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.357 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/gc/heap.cc:293]
>   7215f000-73b89000 r-xp 01a92000 1f:01 7052
>   /data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@boot.oat
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.357 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/gc/heap.cc:293]
>   73b89000-73b8a000 rw-p 034bc000 1f:01 7052
>   /data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@boot.oat
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.357 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/gc/heap.cc:293]
>   73b8a000-77b8a000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 16488
>   /dev/ashmem/dalvik-zygote space (deleted)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.357 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/gc/heap.cc:293]
>   b3ab5000-b3adb000 r--p 00976000 1f:01 7051
>   /data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@boot.art
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.357 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/gc/heap.cc:293]
>   b3adb000-b3adc000 r-xp 00000000 1f:00 898
>   /system/lib/libsigchain.so
>
> ... (for brevity)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.415 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/gc/heap.cc:293]
>   b7780000-b7781000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.415 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/gc/heap.cc:293]
>   b7781000-b7782000 r--p 00016000 1f:00 258        /system/bin/linker
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.415 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/gc/heap.cc:293]
>   b7782000-b7783000 rw-p 00017000 1f:00 258        /system/bin/linker
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.415 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/gc/heap.cc:293]
>   b7783000-b7784000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.415 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/gc/heap.cc:293]
>   b7784000-b7788000 r-xp 00000000 1f:00 194
>   /system/bin/app_process32
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.415 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/gc/heap.cc:293]
>   b7788000-b7789000 r--p 00003000 1f:00 194
>   /system/bin/app_process32
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.415 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/gc/heap.cc:293]
>   b7789000-b778a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.417 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/gc/heap.cc:293]
>   bff3f000-bff60000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.417 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/gc/heap.cc:293]
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.421 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]
>   Runtime aborting...
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.422 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]
>   (Aborting thread was not attached to runtime!)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.422 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]
>   native: #00 pc 00005d03  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so
>   (UnwindCurrent::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+83)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.422 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]
>   native: #01 pc 00003051  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so
>   (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+33)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.422 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]
>   native: #02 pc 003c9e67  /system/lib/libart.so
>   (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream >&, int, char const*,
>   art::mirror::ArtMethod*)+135)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.422 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]
>   native: #03 pc 003777cb  /system/lib/libart.so
>   (art::AbortState::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream >&)+267)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.424 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]
>   native: #04 pc 00377ead  /system/lib/libart.so
>   (art::Runtime::Abort()+125)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.424 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]
>   native: #05 pc 000ec704  /system/lib/libart.so
>   (art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+1876)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.424 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]
>   native: #06 pc 001ec6cc  /system/lib/libart.so
>   (art::gc::Heap::Heap(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int,
>   unsigned int, double, double, unsigned int, unsigned int,
>   std::__1::basic_string,
>   std::__1::allocator > const&, art::InstructionSet,
>   art::gc::CollectorType, art::gc::CollectorType, unsigned int, unsigned
>   int, bool, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool,
>   bool, bool, bool, bool, unsigned long long)+10476)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.424 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]
>   native: #07 pc 0037a32b  /system/lib/libart.so
>   (art::Runtime::Init(std::__1::vector, std::__1::allocator >, void
>   const*>,
>   std::__1::allocator, std::__1::allocator >, void const*>
>
> > > const&, bool)+1387)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.424 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]
>   native: #08 pc 0037d6a8  /system/lib/libart.so
>   (art::Runtime::Create(std::__1::vector, std::__1::allocator >, void
>   const*>,
>   std::__1::allocator, std::__1::allocator >, void const*>
>
> > > const&, bool)+104)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.424 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]
>   native: #09 pc 002ff0fd  /system/lib/libart.so (JNI_CreateJavaVM+1117)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.424 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]
>   native: #10 pc 00072bfa  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
>   (android::AndroidRuntime::startVm(_JavaVM**, _JNIEnv**, bool)+2346)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.424 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]
>   native: #11 pc 00073a80  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
>   (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*,
>   android::Vector const&, bool)+368)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.424 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]
>   native: #12 pc 000018b1  /system/bin/app_process32 (???)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.424 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]
>   native: #13 pc 00012f94  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+100)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.424 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]
>   native: #14 pc 00001b66  /system/bin/app_process32 (???)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.426 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]
>   native: #15 pc 00000004  ???
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.426 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]
>   Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock
>   mutator lock
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.426 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289] All
>   threads:
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.426 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]
>   DALVIK THREADS (0):
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.426 6545-6545/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:289]
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.426 6545-6545/? A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code
>   -6 in tid 6545 (zygote)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.547 939-939/? I/DEBUG: *****       *****
>
> ---
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.547 939-939/? I/DEBUG: Build fingerprint:
>   'Android/sdk_google_phone_x86/generic_x86:5.1.1/LMY48X/2524186:userdebug/test-keys'
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.547 939-939/? I/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.547 939-939/? I/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86'
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.547 939-939/? I/DEBUG: pid: 6545, tid: 6545, name:
>   zygote  >>> zygote <<<
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.547 939-939/? I/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6
>   (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.551 939-939/? I/DEBUG: Abort message:
>   'art/runtime/gc/heap.cc:293] Check failed: main_mem_map_1.get() !=
>   nullptr Failed anonymous mmap(0x0, -2147483648, 0x3, 0x2, 4, 0): Out
>   of memory'
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.551 939-939/? I/DEBUG:     eax 00000000  ebx 00001991 
>   ecx 00001991  edx 00000006
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.552 939-939/? I/DEBUG:     esi b7782c48  edi 0000000c
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.552 939-939/? I/DEBUG:     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b 
>   xes 0000007b  xfs 00000000  xss 0000007b
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.552 939-939/? I/DEBUG:     eip b750fd86  ebp 00001991 
>   esp bff5d8b0  flags 00000286
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.552 939-939/? I/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00073d86 
>   /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+22)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.552 939-939/? I/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0002217b 
>   /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+155)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.552 939-939/? I/DEBUG:     #02 pc 000239f4 
>   /system/lib/libc.so (raise+36)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.552 939-939/? I/DEBUG:     #03 pc 0001bdf4 
>   /system/lib/libc.so (abort+84)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.552 939-939/? I/DEBUG:     #04 pc 00377f56 
>   /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort()+294)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.553 939-939/? I/DEBUG:     #05 pc 000ec704 
>   /system/lib/libart.so (art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+1876)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.553 939-939/? I/DEBUG:     #06 pc 001ec6cc 
>   /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::Heap(unsigned int, unsigned int,
>   unsigned int, unsigned int, double, double, unsigned int, unsigned
>   int, std::__1::basic_string,
>   std::__1::allocator > const&, art::InstructionSet,
>   art::gc::CollectorType, art::gc::CollectorType, unsigned int, unsigned
>   int, bool, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool,
>   bool, bool, bool, bool, unsigned long long)+10476)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.553 939-939/? I/DEBUG:     #07 pc 0037a32b 
>   /system/lib/libart.so
>   (art::Runtime::Init(std::__1::vector, std::__1::allocator >, void
>   const*>,
>   std::__1::allocator, std::__1::allocator >, void const*>
>
> > > const&, bool)+1387)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.553 939-939/? I/DEBUG:     #08 pc 0037d6a8 
>   /system/lib/libart.so
>   (art::Runtime::Create(std::__1::vector, std::__1::allocator >, void
>   const*>,
>   std::__1::allocator, std::__1::allocator >, void const*>
>
> > > const&, bool)+104)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.553 939-939/? I/DEBUG:     #09 pc 002ff0fd 
>   /system/lib/libart.so (JNI_CreateJavaVM+1117)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.553 939-939/? I/DEBUG:     #10 pc 00072bfa 
>   /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
>   (android::AndroidRuntime::startVm(_JavaVM**, _JNIEnv**, bool)+2346)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.553 939-939/? I/DEBUG:     #11 pc 00073a80 
>   /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char
>   const*, android::Vector const&, bool)+368)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.553 939-939/? I/DEBUG:     #12 pc 000018b1 
>   /system/bin/app_process32
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.553 939-939/? I/DEBUG:     #13 pc 00012f94 
>   /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+100)
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.553 939-939/? I/DEBUG:     #14 pc 00001b66 
>   /system/bin/app_process32
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.554 939-939/? I/DEBUG:     #15 pc 00000004
>
> 01-22 05:48:40.627 929-929/? I/ServiceManager: service
>   'media.audio_flinger' died

My **.avd** folder is located at *C:\Users\maffe* and as you can see HAXM is working.

My emulator device is:

- Nexus 6
- Lollipop
- API 22
- Target is Google APIs
- CPU x86
- Uses Host GPU
- No camera
- 1536MB of RAM
- 2GB of VM heap
- 200MB of internal storage
- Enable Device Frame is checked

I am myself running the following computer:

- Intel Core i5-3470 CPU @ 3.2GHz
- 12GB RAM
- 64 bit Windows 10
- About a 2 week old setup (from a fresh Windows installation)

Any idea why it would get stuck on the loop shown in the Logcat output? All I see is the black screen with the 'Android' sign on it (which of course is better then the black-only-screen I get if I uncheck Use Host GPU).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the problem. I had accidentally set the **VM heap** to 2GB. I should've left it at 64MB :)

Comment: The need to use adb to find this problem seems very frustrating. Would be much more appropriate to report this at the user level as some kind of early check. Probably wasted a day finding the exact cause. Had changed the value after finding that there was another issue with it being too small.

Answer (score 0):

Emulator could be running out of memory.  Lower the VM heap or memory option in the AVD manager.  That worked for me.  when looping with a `nullptr Failed anonymous mmap` error.

Answer (score 0):

I Manually run the installer for HAXM, Path:

```
C:\users\username\appdata\local\android\sdk\extras\intel\hardware_accelarated_execution_management\
```

Run the `.exe` file.